# How can i set message headers on massTransit 4.X

Tags: c#, masstransit

when i am in massTransit 3.x,i use follow code to set message header before send，its work.

```
public class SendObserver : ISendObserver
{
    public Task PostSend<T>(SendContext<T> context) where T : class
    {
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public Task PreSend<T>(SendContext<T> context) where T : class
    {
        //1. get current thread identity object.
        var currentThreadIdentityObject = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity is JustIMIdentity ? (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as JustIMIdentity).IdentityObject : null;

        if (currentThreadIdentityObject != null)
        {
            //2. set the headers.
            context.Headers.Set(AppSettingConfig.RabbitMqIdentityHeaderKey, currentThreadIdentityObject.StaffID);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public Task SendFault<T>(SendContext<T> context, Exception exception) where T : class
    {
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

and i register in autofac

```
        //register in autofac
        builder.Register(context =>
        {
            var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                var uri = AppSettingConfig.RabbitMqBaseUri;

                var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(uri), x =>
                {
                    x.Username(AppSettingConfig.RabbitMqUserName);
                    x.Password(AppSettingConfig.RabbitMqUserPassword);
                });
            });

            busControl.ConnectSendObserver(new SendObserver());

            busControl.Start();

            return busControl;
        })
        .SingleInstance()
        .As<IBusControl>()
        .As<IBus>();

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RequestClient<,>)).AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

but when i update massTransit to 4.X,the message in queue is without header,it look like set header is not working,whats going on.

Comment: Observers are not made to manipulate messages or context. Observers are to _observe_. Write a custom middleware to change headers http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/middleware/custom.html